# I do not know Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

I am making a Web application using Ruby on Rails now.
However, it may be in trouble.
Routing when the show action is invoked article (articles) that will be displayed is currently `hoge.com/articles/ (article id)`. I want to /hoge.com/username/ (article id), but can not quite.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
devise_scope :user do
  resources :articles
  get '/:username', controller: 'users', action: 'show'
  get '/users/sign_out', controller: 'devise/sessions', action: 'destroy'
  get 'users/auth/:provider/disconnect', controller: 'omniauth_disconnects', action: 'update'
end
post 'user_invitation_beta_release/new'
get 'static/welcome'
root to: 'root#index'
resources :items
resources :contents
resources :articles do
  resources :contents, only: [:create, :destroy, :change_order] do
    resources :items, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
match "*path" => "application#handle_404", via: :all
```

Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get '/:username/:article_id', controller: 'articles', action: 'show'
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from a fuller explanation and perhaps links to documentation.